# How to convert firestore collection to useful object

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, google-cloud-firestore, mapping

I have a collection of currencies in firestore called "currencies". The collection has documents named after the currency (e. g. "euro", "dollar", etc.).

I am querying the collection and receive an array of all documents in the collection like so:

```
[{euro:{dollar: 2}},
{dollar:{euro: 0.5}}]
```

I would like to turn this into an Object with document ids as the object keys like so:

```
{{euro:{dollar: 2}},
{dollar:{euro: 0.5}}}
```

So that I can access Object.keys(obj) to access all available currencies like so:

```
console.log(Object.keys(obj)) ---> [euro], [dollar]
```

This seems dead simple to me, but I am struggling how to achieve this as I don't understand the difference between array.map, array.foreach array.reduce, Object.assign, etc.

Which one should I use and which is the most elegant (read: shortest) to do so?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use object destructuring or `Object.assign()` in a `reduce()`

```js
const data = [{euro:{dollar: 2}},{dollar:{euro: 0.5}}]

const res = data.reduce((a, c) => ({...a, ...c}), {});
// or res = data.reduce((a, c) => Object.assign(a, c), {});   

console.log(res)
```

Comment: Thanks Charlie! Will try at home and report back. But this looks good. I will have to read up on the expansion thing (...a). Seems to be the right way to go. Much appreciated.